# PHP - MYSQL RECORDS SHOW MULTIPLE

Tags: php, mysql

I created a code that shows a category from the ITEMS in record.

If ITEM 1 is Phones, the code shows phones. But the problem is when have more than 2 with the same Category, the code shows 2 times or more the same category
[image]

My code is

```
$select_parent = "SELECT ads_id, ads_title, category_id FROM public_ads WHERE ads_active = 1 AND ads_genre = 'Loja' AND ads_end = 0";
$parent_query = $con->query($select_parent);

if($parent_query->num_rows > 0) {
                            
    while($parents = $parent_query->fetch_assoc()) {

        $select_categories = "SELECT category_id, category_title FROM public_categories WHERE category_id = '".$parents['category_id']."' ORDER BY category_id Limit 1";
        $category_query = $con->query($select_categories);            
        
        while($options = $category_query->fetch_assoc()) {

           echo '<li><a href="store?p='. $parents['category_id'] .'&article='. $options['category_title'] .'"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> '. $options['category_title'] .'</a></li>';
        }

   }                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY category_id` at the end of your query (after the `WHERE`clause). This will limit the result to one row per category_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "DISTINCT".... as in "SELECT DISTINCT ads_id...."